# VoLTE Indication

Tags: iphone

Wifi calling provides an indicator so that the user knows that wifi calling is engaged: very useful when roaming abroad.

Is there a similar indicator to enable the user to understand if VoLTE is engaged and not cellular: this would be helpful to understand if a call is using accruing roaming fees, when out of network.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it’s painfully obvious that the call quality is much better on VoLTE and FaceTime audio calls.

There is no indicator, so you’d [need your carrier](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203078) to break that out if you can’t record or tell from the higher quality and larger frequency range / response.

It’s of course possible a carrier could direct you to VoLTE and the codec degrade, so this isn’t a guarantee, but it is striking enough that I generally can hear the difference.